# onClick, onmouseenter and onmouseleave work only when the mouse is on the DIV border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, onclick, border

I'm trying to write an extension for IE. it works fine on most sites but on youtube.com onClick, onmouseenter and onmouseleave work only when the mouse is on the border of an element (div) and not when inside the element.

any suggestions?
thanks.

Comment: tired onmouseover and there was no change. the problem persist.

Comment: you got it in an iframe ? probably iframe not communicating mouse position due to cross domain. put a invisiblle div over the top of the frame and collect mouseovers like that.

Comment: i'm not using iframe.
i'm using c++ to write a flash blocker extension. if there is a flash object in the page, i'm placing a div on top of it. if you click on that div, the flash is enabled.

Comment: you'll have to give us some code that isn't working and we'll try and sort it from there.

Comment: unfortunately i can't give you the code. it's a huge project with many classes. even the part where i'm creating the div and the part where i'm attaching the onClick event are in different classes. I hope you can help me without the code. I have tired googling it for a few days with no luck.

Comment: how can anyone here help you with no code......sorry